# How to create local media server for live streaming?

Tags: linux, video, local-storage, media, lan

So,
 I have one linux system.and i need to convert it to local media server i.e. i will upload songs,video on that system and other users connected to same lan/different lan can access it and listen to songs/video without downloading them.its like a local streaming server.The whole system should be offline.

any software bundle ?installation steps ?
any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"The whole system should be offline"-- terminology issue: 'offline' usually implies no network connectivity. If this system is serving media on a network, it is necessarily 'online'.

This is a pretty open-ended question. The specific solution you pursue will hinge on a few issues such as:

- How the end users will consume media? Browser? Standalone media player?
- What type of media will you stream? Do you already have a corpus of media that you intend to stream? Are you free to convert media into whatever format is most convenient?

The simplest way to create a local streaming server would be to host the media files on a standard web server and serve them via normal HTTP. For delivering them, create a simple web page that leverages the HTML5 `<video>` and `<audio>` tags. If you control the web browser experience on the network (e.g., corporate intranet), you just need one set of media files. If you need to support multiple browsers, you may need multiple copies of each file.

Comment: actually we have an old linux desktop in our office and we want to make it as media storage server.such that media files will be stored there and each person in office can access that system and listen to music,or video on that system through lan without downloading it.

Comment: end users should communicate through LAN.browser based.simple media mp3 files or videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can try mt-daapd http://www.deleet.de/projekte/daap/daapd/. I think, this suitable waht you need. But, the mt-daapd only support audio.

or you can install OS that support media server like FreeNAS http://www.freenas.org